# How can I template the vcard with jekyll to be able to save the import into apple/android

Tags: jekyll, liquid, vcf-vcard

Jekyll does generate the contact.vcf file. I can open it on win10 contacts or iphone 7+ contact manager. It will not save, however. I suspect I have a syntax error in the VCF format?

I have reviewed [rfc6350 standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350). I may have missed something?

```
---
layout: null
permalink: /vcard.vcf
---
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
KIND:org
N:;;;
FN:
ORG:{{site.title}};Customer Service
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=image/PNG:{% base64 http://legaldemo.strikehawk.com/assets/images/balance-scale-solid.png %}
LOGO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=image/PNG:{% base64 http://legaldemo.strikehawk.com/assets/images/balance-scale-solid.png %}
item1.ADR;type=work:;;{{site.addr}};{{site.city}};{{site.state}};{{site.zip}};{{site.country}};;GEO="geo:{{site.lat}},{{site.long}}";TZ:{{site.timezone}};LANG:{{site.lang}}
item1.X-ABADR:us
TEL;type=MAIN,VOICE,MSG:{{site.tel}}
item2.URL;TYPE=WORK;TYPE=pref:https://{{site.url}}
item2.X-ABLABEL:_$!<HomePage>!$_
X-ABShowAs:COMPANY
EMAIL;type=internet,work:{{site.email}}
CATEGORIES:Legal Services,Attorney
PROFILE:VCARD
ROLE:Legal Services
SOURCE:http://{{site.url}}/vcard.vcf
EXPERTISE;LEVEL=expert:Criminal Law, Insurance Litigation
IMPP;X-SERVICE-TYPE=facebook;TYPE=HOME;TYPE=pref:xmpp:{{site.social.facebook}}
IMPP;X-SERVICE-TYPE=googletalk;TYPE=WORK:xmpp:denver.prophit@gmail.com
X-SOCIALPROFILE;type=twitter;x-user={{site.social.twitter}}:https://twitter.com/{{site.social.twitter}}
X-SOCIALPROFILE;type=facebook;x-user={{site.social.facebook}}:https://facebook.com/{{site.social.facebook}}
REV:{% last_modified_at %Y%m%d %}T13:00:00Z-6:00
END:VCARD
```

The compiled code:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
KIND:org
N:;;;
FN:
ORG:Acme Law Firm;Customer Service
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=image/PNG:data:image/png;base64, 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
LOGO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=image/PNG:data:image/png;base64, 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
item1.ADR;type=work:;;111 ANYWHERE AVE.;HOMETOWN;FL;34482;USA;;GEO="geo:29.20512,-82.31894";TZ:America/New_York;LANG:en-US
item1.X-ABADR:us
TEL;type=MAIN,VOICE,MSG:(352) 123-1234
item2.URL;TYPE=WORK;TYPE=pref:https://legaldemo.strikehawk.com
item2.X-ABLABEL:_$!<HomePage>!$_
X-ABShowAs:COMPANY
EMAIL;type=internet,work:denver.prophit@gmail.com
CATEGORIES:Legal Services,Attorney
PROFILE:VCARD
ROLE:Legal Services
SOURCE:http://legaldemo.strikehawk.com/vcard.vcf
EXPERTISE;LEVEL=expert:Criminal Law, Insurance Litigation
IMPP;X-SERVICE-TYPE=facebook;TYPE=HOME;TYPE=pref:xmpp:denverprophit
IMPP;X-SERVICE-TYPE=googletalk;TYPE=WORK:xmpp:denver.prophit@gmail.com
X-SOCIALPROFILE;type=twitter;x-user=DenverProphitJr:https://twitter.com/DenverProphitJr
X-SOCIALPROFILE;type=facebook;x-user=denverprophit:https://facebook.com/denverprophit
REV:20190603T13:00:00Z-6:00
END:VCARD
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Denver!

What parts of the standards have you reviewed?

In the PHOTO and LOGO properties, there is a space character after "base64," which shouldn't be there.

EDIT:

The format of the REV property is also incorrect. It should be: `20190603T070000Z`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html also has a space after base64. The Jekyll plugin comes from https://github.com/GSI/jekyll_image_encode

Comment: I see what you mean after reading the standard. I've created an issue https://github.com/GSI/jekyll_image_encode/issues/7 that takes care of the image and logo. Would that prevent the vcard from being saved?